# how to use pull to refresh facility in listbox for windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am building an app where i get data in my listbox from web service. I need to use the refresh facility so that when new data comes when i am using that page it should be automatically refreshed instead of calling the web service again. My code both xaml and cs is given below. Please help.

Xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged"  Height="676" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <Button IsHitTestVisible="False">
           <Button.Content>
              <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="80" Width="400">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                     <Image Source="{Binding ImageBind }" Height="90" Width="95"/>
                          <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>

       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date_Start}" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>
           </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                  </ScrollViewer>
                     </Button.Content>
                   </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

My cs file:

```
 public class Newss
    {
        public string News_Title { get; set; }
        public string News_Description { get; set; }
        public string Date_Start { get; set; }
        public string image_path { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage ImageBind{get;set;}

      }

    public const string NewssXml = "Newss.xml";

    public News()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        bool isSuccess;
        //try to load data from iso store
        var doc = ReadXml(out isSuccess);
        if (isSuccess) PopulateList(doc);
        //if failed (data doesn't exists in iso store), download data from web service
        else
        {
            KejriwalService.aapSoapClient client = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
            client.getarvindNewsCompleted += new EventHandler<KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getarvindNewsCompleted);
            client.getarvindNewsAsync();

            progressName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    //upon download completed, display data then save the xml to iso store
    void client_getarvindNewsCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
        PopulateList(doc);
        WriteXml(doc);
    }

    private void PopulateList(XDocument doc)
    {
        List<Newss> listData = new List<Newss>();

        progressName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

        foreach (var location in doc.Descendants("UserDetails"))
        {
            Newss data = new Newss();
            data.News_Title = location.Element("News_Title").Value;
            data.News_Description = location.Element("News_Description").Value;
            data.Date_Start = location.Element("Date_Start").Value;
            data.image_path = location.Element("image_path").Value;
            data.ImageBind = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"http://political-leader.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal/images/uploaded/" + data.image_path, UriKind.Absolute));
            listData.Add(data);
        }
        listBox1.ItemsSource = listData;
    }

    private XDocument ReadXml(out bool isSuccess)
    {
        isSuccess = false;
        var doc = new XDocument();
        using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            try
            {
                if (store.FileExists(NewssXml))
                {
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(NewssXml, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, store)))
                    {
                        doc = XDocument.Load(sr);
                    }
                    isSuccess = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
        return doc;
    }

    private bool WriteXml(XDocument document)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            try
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(NewssXml, FileMode.Create, store)))
                {
                    sw.Write(document.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void Image_Back(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AAP.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing

        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;

        Newss news = listBox1.SelectedItem as Newss;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewsDetails.xaml?News_Title=" + news.News_Title + "&News_Description=" + news.News_Description +"&Date_Start=" +news.Date_Start + "&image_path=" + news.image_path, UriKind.Relative));

        // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }




 }
```

}

Comment: Pull-to-refresh is an iOS paradigm. Add refresh button to `ApplicationBar`

Comment: No it isn't. It's a mobile concept. IOS doesn't have this out of the box. It's a third party thing that has become standard on many platforms because it just works awesome on mobile. You even see the Microsoft made apps on WP use this.

Answer (score 0):

See my blog post here: http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2011/04/03/RefreshBox-for-Windows-Phone-7.aspx
note this work on WP7, but doesn't run very well if compiled for WP8 (compiled for wp7 and running on wp8 is fine).

Comment: can anyone please write some codes for my app that i posted above to avail pull to refresh?

Comment: @har07 hey can u please help me on this issue?